# Using jQuery .animate() on elements that don't have position: absolute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to design a website where a dropdown menu is triggered when the user clicks on an image. My jQuery uses the following method to do this:

```
function main() {
    $('#arrow').click(function() {
        $('.hidden').animate({
            top: '200px'
        }, 400);

        $('#arrow').animate({
            top: '400px'
        }, 400);

        $('#arrow').css("src", "uparrow.jpg");
    });
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

This works fine for dropping the menu down, but it covers up my page content when it does. This is okay, but I'd really like an effect that pushes the entire page below the menu down. The catch is, I'd rather not have to set `position: absolute;` on all of the elements in order to animate them. Here are the CSS attributes of the menu and related elements for reference:

```
    /* Menu elements */

.hidden {
  z-index: -5;
  top: -50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#arrow {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: block;
}

#arrow-box {
  background-color: white; /* FOR NOW */
}

#dropdown {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}
```

Here is a Stack Snippet for clarity:

```js
function main() {
  $('#arrow').click(function(){
    $('.hidden').animate({
      top: '200px'
    }, 400);

    $('#arrow').animate({
      top: '400px'
    }, 400);

    $('#arrow').css("src", "uparrow.jpg");
  });
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

/* Menu elements */

.hidden {
  z-index: -5;
  top: -50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#arrow {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: block;
}

#arrow-box {
  background-color: white; /* FOR NOW */
}

#banner {
  background-color: gray; /* For now, until I get some pictures in */
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

#dropdown {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

/* Fonts and such */

h1 {
  color: white;
  margin: 0px;
}

ul {
  margin: 0px;
}

.unstyled {
  list-style-type: none;
}

/* General structural elements */

#content {
  width: 75%;
  height: 500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

/* Footer stuff */

footer {
  height: 350px;
  background-color: gray; /* FOR NOW */
}

#footer-border {
  background-color: black; /* Probably dark blue later */
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
}

.left {
  padding: 10px;
}

.fields {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="banner">
      <h1>Company Name Placeholder</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="dropdown" class="hidden">
      <ul id="menu" class="hidden unstyled">
        <li>PLACEHOLDER</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="arrow-box">
      <img id="arrow" src="downarrow.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      Page content will go here.
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div id="footer-border"></div>
        <div class="left">
          This will be about customers contacting me, etc.
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <form id="contact" method="post" action"#" accept-charset="UTF-8">
            <ul class="fields unstyled">
              <li class="fields"><label for="email-address">E-Mail</label><input name="email-address"></input></li>
              <li class="fields"><label for="subject">Subject</label><input name="subject"></input></li>
              <li class="fields"><label for="message"></label><input name="message"></input></li>
            </ul>
          </form>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <!-- Scripts down here -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="menu.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think we need a demo to understand what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Can use a number of code share sites like jsfiddle.net for demos

Comment: A **reduced case** demonstraton (either in JSfiddle.net) or a Stack Snippet of the relevant HTML/CSS/JQ sowe can see what effect you are after.

Comment: I added a snippet, sorry if it made the post a bit long.

Comment: What about animating a top-margin for the content area concurrently?

Comment: I like that idea! I'm going to try it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: .animate() Only seems to accept `margin` and not `margin-top`.

Comment: Never mind. Writing it as `marginTop` seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to animate a relatively positioned element because every step of the animation will recalculate a large portion (if not the entire) DOM. This will look bad on PC and worse on mobile.

The performant solution here is to position your menu and content absolutely and move both simultaneously.

You can achieve even smoother performance by moving your elements around using CSS3's `transform` and `transition` properties to enable hardware acceleration. You can find a tutorial on this [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/).